# Copy entire row of top nth's in a column

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I have a table of "Orders."  It has columns "Customer Name," "Order Number," "Order date," and a helper column, "Days Old."  I also have a dashboard where I would like the oldest 5 orders to be displayed. 
How could I accomplish this?

I'm able to do this with the 'large' function, however, the index/match to get the customer name and order number associated with the date does not work as two dates can be the same.
[image]

Comment: That means you got multiple rows that have the same value in your helper column? If so, what is your definition of Top 5? Can they have the same value in the helper column and as such is this the reason your INDEX/MATCH would pick up on the same values? Some mockup markdown sample data would be helpfull with a desired output. Also, you do really have got a table object?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple rows with the same helper value.  (I've changed it to "Days old" instead of "Weeks old" but same concept).  My top 5 would be the five largest in the helper column whether their all 5 the same or unique.  The data is not in a table object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your "Order Date" **does not** have Time data *(e.g., number 43749.00 for October 11 2019; number 43749.51 for October 11 2019 at 12:15PM)*. If your "Order Date" **does** have this data, then your "Weeks Old" calculation does in fact have unique calculations and thus identifiers for orders, unless order were placed at the same exact time.

In any case, I suggest using a **Pivot Table** on the "Weeks Old", which you can format to summarize columns based on the non-unique "Weeks Old" value. **In other words, you'll be able to see all data which have the same "Weeks Old" value, in the order which you specify.**

Your dashboard can then link to the cells of this Pivot Table, once the relevant columns have been dragged into thie "Rows" area in the order you specify.

*Note, you'll need to change the Field Settings for each "Row" to have "None" for **Subtotals**; and "Show item labels in tabular form" and "Repeat item labels" for **Layout***